# How can you constantly check when the height of the scrollbar has changed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to detect whenever the user changes the height of the scrollbar. Right now the script I have detects it once (when the user moves the scrollbar down) but when you move the scrollbar again nothing happens. My logic is that when the user moves the scrollbar to a position greater than 296 a div appears using animate(), and this works. But when the user moves the scrollbar to a position less than 296 the div should disappear using animate(). My code is below. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var wintop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docheight = $(document).height();
  var winheight = $(window).height();

  var newWidthGrow = 500;
  var smallHeight = 0;
  var smallWidth = 0;


  if(wintop > 296) 
  {

    $("#slidebottom").animate({height:docheight +"px", width:newWidthGrow + "px"},'fast');          
  }

  if(wintop < 296)
  { 
    $("#slidebottom").animate({height:smallheight +"px", width:smallWidth + "px"}, 'fast');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here:

You initiate a variable named `smallHeight` but you use `smallheight`, which causes an error.

You should add the `.stop()`-method before running another animation like that:

```
$("#slidebottom").stop().animate();
```

And you should consider to run each animation only once and not any time the scroll event is fired. A boolean can be helpful here:

```
if(wintop < 296 && expanded) {
    expanded = false;
    $("#slidebottom").stop().animate();
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Xbn/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help! You taught me a lot.